# Why is my backend endpoint not working on my deployed Asp.net core with react project?

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, iis

I've deployed an asp.net core with react project to somee.com, The frontend loads just fine but axios.get is returning this:

```json
{
    "message": "Network Error",
    "name": "AxiosError",
    "stack": "AxiosError: Network Error\n    at l.onerror (http://something.somee.com/static/js/main.17849c8f.js:2:700322)",
    "config": {
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "adapter": [
            "xhr",
            "http"
        ],
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "env": {},
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
        },
        "method": "get",
        "url": "http://something.somee.com:5030/api/user/null"
    },
    "code": "ERR_NETWORK",
    "status": null
}
```

I did the following to ensure the endpoint is setup correctly:

for every axios request:

```js
const apiUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;
const response = await axios.get(`${apiUrl}/user/taskss/${params.id}`);
```

with the .env file being:

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://something.somee.com:5030
```

I also did this on appsettings.js:

```json
"Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://something.somee.com:5030"
      }
    }
  },
```

And the Program.cs:

```cs
var hostBuilder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);

// Set the listening URL using the UseUrls method
hostBuilder.UseUrls("http://something.somee.com:5030");

var app = builder.Build();

// Enable CORS
app.UseCors(options => options
    .AllowAnyOrigin()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
);
```

and still nothing, what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Does your project work fine locally? or does the problem only occur on iis?

Comment: @samwu It's working locally just fine, I just need to change http://something.somee.com:5030 to localhost:5030 and it works just fine.

Comment: Please check if you have set domain name? Open the Notepad, go to File -> Open. Get to C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc and make sure to select All Files to find the hosts file. Now you can edit the hosts file. Add the custom IP address you've made earlier, followed by a space, then your domain name.

Comment: @samwu I'm sorry i'm confused, what is the Drivers folder doing here? Also I've changed the host to a windows server with IIS, and still the same issue even though i've added a binding for http://something.somee.com:5030 port.

Comment: The reason `localhost` works is because it is already bound to the ip address in the hosts file, so you need to bind `something.somee.com` to the ip address.